# Specify Dynamic IP of SSH server on the client side

Tags: ssh, ip, dynamic

I am trying to set up a ssh server at home connected to internet via wireless router. Since its IP is dynamic, how do you specify its address on the client side? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) (or similar service), combined with port-forwarding and a static local IP address on the client is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You mean dynamic internally, set by DHCP? You would need to assign your server a static IP instead of a DHCP-assigned address.

If you mean your home address is dynamic from the outside network, you can either try a service like dynamic DNS or do what I do; my leases are rather long so I just go to www.whatismyip.com and write it down and that lease will keep for weeks (or months) at a time, but it varies by provider.

Another thing you can rig up is a way to script an automatic grab of your external IP and email it to you periodically.

Your only other "easy" option I know of is to check the provider's offerings and see if they'll offer a static IP to your location, but usually that's for business class lines. Plus they frown on the possibility that you're going to run a web server or mail server.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use some web dynamic IP services, like dyndns.
it offers a free web IP detection tool for use with dyndns services, and it's supported by many ADSL routers.
After you need to do, is to enable NAT at your firewall and configure it
to forward port 20000 (For example) to your local server inside the NAT at the port of your sshd.

Try to change the standard ssh port to another port (20000) to get less ssh brute force attack.

Comment: +1 for mentioning port forwarding (I think)